# How to configure Obfuscar, The Open Source Obfuscation Tool

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscar

I m trying to use the [obfuscar](https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/) free tool to protect my code from reverse engineering. I'm trying to obfuscate the provided example [Basic Example](https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Example&referringTitle=Documentation). The problem that I can't find how to configure it.

Here's my config.xml

```
<configuration>

  <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" 
     sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
  </startup>

  <Obfuscator>

    <Var name="InPath"  value="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Obfuscar_2.0.0\Examples\BasicExample\BasicExampleExe\bin\Debug" />
    <Var name="OutPath" value="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Obfuscar_2.0.0\Examples\BasicExample\BasicExampleExe\bin\Debug" />

    <Module file="$(InPath)\BasicExampleExe.exe" />
    <Module file="$(InPath)\BasicExampleLibrary.dll" />
    <Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="true" />
    <Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />

  </Obfuscator>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You will have to study some MSBuild script, and then read `release.proj` to see how to get everything working.

Comment: This seems to be (yet) another example of a programmer completely leaving the intended user - in this case other coders! - completely at sea. If you're going to spend all that time and effort creating an application/utility, for god's sake, tell people how to use it. Every second project I see on GitHub is the same. [Alights soapbox]

Comment: @CoderDennis That link is now a 404. See my other comment ...

Comment: @SteveCinq I never did get this or any other open source obfuscators to work. I've deleted my comment that had a broken link.

Comment: @CoderDennis I have got it going - probably took more of my time than `Eazfuscator` cost in the end! It mostly works quite well but it can't handle re-signing with pfx which is a bit annoying. So I added a post-event to re-sign using `SignTool` and it's now fine. I never got the source code worked out, tho. Why people don't publish complete, tested, working solutions I'll never understand. BTW, I thought `Eazfuscator` was really good and "eaz"(!) to use. That's my fall-back.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question... the example Release.proj build file they provide in the Git attempts to build the Obfuscar binary from scratch. So you need to change two lines of the Release.proj file, assuming you're going to be using the pre-compiled Obfuscar binary file.

First, change the path to the ObfuscarExe path to where you have the binary saved similar to this:

```
<!-- obfuscator bits -->
<PropertyGroup>
        <ObfuscatorExe>C:\Program Files (x86)\Obfuscar\obfuscar.Console.exe</ObfuscatorExe>
        <ObfuscatorProject>$(BasePath)\obfuscar.xml</ObfuscatorProject>
        <ObfuscatorInput>$(BasePath)\Obfuscator_Input</ObfuscatorInput>
        <ObfuscatorOutput>$(BasePath)\Obfuscator_Output</ObfuscatorOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Second, comment out the command to compile the Obfuscar solution:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <CompileSolution Include="$(BasePath)\BasicExample.sln" />
    <!-- <CompileObfuscar Include="..\..\Obfuscar\Obfuscar.sln" /> -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: When I follow these instructions I just get an error: "BasicExample\Release.proj" (default target) (1) ->
  BasicExample\Release.proj(28,2): error MSB4067: The element <#text> beneath element <PropertyGroup> is unrecognized.